# copy_from_user function : write with offsert

Tags: linux, kernel-module

I'm developping simple kernel modul which read and write in buffer,I have this structure of buffer.

```
    // Data buffers structure 
    typedef struct dnode
    {
      int   bufSize;
      char *buffer;
      struct dnode *nextNode;
} data_node;
data_node *newNode
```

now suppose that I want to copy from user to the struct buf data with size lower then bufSize, so next time I want to copy starting from the end of last copied data :

```
ex: blocSIze = 512
```

I copy 10, so 502 left, so next time I want to copy in the same buffer in the 502 free space and so one

what shall I modify in `copy_from_user` function to be able to copy with offset in buffer struct

```
copy_from_user(newNode->buffer, buf, size);
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but if you want to copy to `char* buffer` at offset `10` then simply pass `buffer + 10` as first argument.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to copy to `char* buffer` at offset `10` then simply pass `buffer + 10` as first argument. –  zch